# During linking phase of C++ code on ubuntu: libasan.so.6: warning: the use of `tmpnam_r' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc-warning

I am building my C++ program, at linking stage I am getting this warning message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.6: warning: the use of `tmpnam' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.6: warning: the use of `tempnam' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'
```

Actually huge number of the above duplicated messages.  I saw posting discussing the mechanism of this warning.  My questions is how do I fix this warning from a programmer point of view, or as a sysadmin.  There are many similar postings. My OS is Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, 5.15.0-60-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 20 14:29:49 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux.

```
gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

No where in my code I used the tempnam or tmpnam_r function.  Must be one of the included code indirectly used the two functions.

Comment: Do you want to know how to _fix_ the warnings, or how to _suppress_ the warnings? Fixing requires finding the offending use of the functions and replacing them as suggested.

Comment: `libasan.so` is the one making the mistake. You're not going to change `libasan.so`, so you need to suppress it. The exact mechanism will depend on your build system. Are you invoking `g++` from the command line? Or using something like CMake?

Comment: I build my own make file from autotools.  I am using command line entirely. Looks just have to live with libasan.so. I am trying to see anything that I can do to avoid. The warning is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My warning messages were gong after the following operations:

1. Reconfigure [libplot](https://github.com/kemin711/Plotutils) package with configure --enable-libplotter. Reinstall.
2. Reconfigure and reinstall two other dependency packages of my own source code.
   Then reconfigure and rebuild my package.

My problem may be related to my system update. Another possibility might be related to some my dependency package used -fsanitize=address option during configuration. Now all of my dependencies were rebuild without this gcc compiler option.  Still my answer does not nail the exact source of the problem. Hope can be some help to people in my situation.

Comment: It makes sense that `-fsanitize=address` would cause linking against `libasan`.

Comment: I was suspecting the compiler options. @JohnFilleau now you mentioned it. It is very likely that is the source of problem.

Comment: yes, this definitely *is* the source of that problem. I had the same issue with an own project and the messages were all gone after linking with `-fsanitize`. Strange, that *adding* libraries fixes such a warning ...